# Loop to send an email for each row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, outlook

I can not get Excel to see row three as a separate line of data. My code is adding all the attachments from row three to the email with information generated from row two.

How can I loop through rows 2 to the last row with data?

I am trying to send an email using the information filled in each cell of each row. I am using this current code since it is the only way I can get a signature line to work.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet    
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")        

Dim OutApp As Object    
Dim OutMail As Object        
Dim strbody As String    
Dim I As Integer    
Dim last_row As Integer

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)    
With OutMail    
    last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))    
    For I = 2 To last_row    
        .display    
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = sh.Range("A" & I).Value    
        .To = sh.Range("B" & I).Value    
        .CC = sh.Range("C" & I).Value    
        .Subject = sh.Range("D" & I).Value    
        .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody    
        
        If sh.Range("F" & I).Value <> "" Then    
            .attachments.Add sh.Range("F" & I).Value    
        End If
        
        If sh.Range("G" & I).Value <> "" Then    
            .attachments.Add sh.Range("G" & I).Value    
        End If
        
        If sh.Range("H" & I).Value <> "" Then    
            .attachments.Add sh.Range("H" & I).Value    
        End If
```

I don't think the last part of the code is worth much it is just `strbody =`. I originally wanted the body to be a variable. That presented the problem of not being able to use a signature line.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you had in mind was perhaps as shown below. The code creates an email text, including some snippets from the worksheet, which can then be assigned to the `HTMLbody`.

```
Dim Txt As String
Dim Line As String
Dim C As Long

Txt = "Dear Sir," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Please take note of the following." & vbNewLine
Line = ""

For C = 6 To 8
    With sh.Cells(i, C)
        If Len(.Value) Then
            If Len(Line) Then Line = Line & ", "
            Line = Line & .Value
        End If
    End With
Next C
If Len(Line) Then Txt = Txt & Line & vbNewLine

Txt = Txt & "Please get back to me ASAP." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
Txt = Txt & " Regards" & vbNewLine & "John Doe"
```